# Rails link_to include protocol and www depending on environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a good way to have `link_to` use the full url, including the protocol ( `https` over `http` ) and `www` but only on in production environment? Development and Staging can stay the same.

Comment: Try path with `_url` Eg: `root_url(protocol: "https")` will give `"https://www.example.com/"`

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you are currently using this kind of code: `link_to my_ressource_path()`.

What you should do:

- **full url**: `link_to my_ressource_url()`
- **https**: change your *config/environments/production.rb* file by adding:

```ruby
routes.default_url_options = { host: 'YOU_WEBSITE_URL', protocol: 'https'  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `*_url` routes helpers over `*_path` helper with `link_to`

e.g you might be using `link_to users_path` then simply use `link_to users_url`